# Need help regarding creating a Regex for email id match

Tags: regex, regex-negation, boost-regex, regex-greedy, regexkitlite

I am very new to regex and need help.

I am looking for a regex which matches only if any of 3 email ids are found in the message headers (lets say a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com and c@rediffmail.com) if there is any email id in sender header then it shouldn't match.

Is it possible to create this kind of regex? if yes, please advise.

Regards,
Goldy
baharja@goldytips.info

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text you are searching in. and perhaps what should and shouldn't match within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

\w+@\w+.\w{3}